# hadoop single node installation - formatting the hadoop file system

Tags: hadoop

I get the following error when I try to format the hdfs :

This is the first time im installing hadoop

```
hduser@dbserver:~$ /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

> /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 297:
>   /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
>   /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 345:
>   /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
>   /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 345: exec:
>   /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or
>   directory

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You need to uncomment and set JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh file most probably.

Comment: thanks for the help . I was able to solve this problem by setting the JAVA_HOME variable to JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"

Comment: it was the  hadoop-env.sh file as you rightly suggested  :). I am getting a different error now. I am not sure if i should raise a separate question or just piggyback in this thread